# Google Cloud Platform Import Into Dataset Failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server, google-cloud-automl

I tried using the Node.js API with GraphQL and Apollo for importing into a dataset for training a machine learning model in GCP (Google Cloud Platform). I get the following error:

```
node --inspect ./gcp-ql.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/b71e0ac0-aa01-4fd0-9894-44e387fc630e
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
  Server ready at http://localhost:4002/
Proccessing import
Proccessing import
9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: No other operations should be working on projects/1044813058227/locations/us-central1/datasets/TCN8942061986888286208.
Currently running operations on the dataset:
        projects/1044813058227/locations/us-central1/operations/TCN7607128426931027968
Call List Operation API to learn more details.
```

For some reason the log statement processing import appears twice which I believe is the function being called twice. Any help on why this is happening will greatly help.

Code used while running the program:

```
const mlClient = new AutoMlClient();
importDataset: async (root, args) => {
           try {
            // Construct request
            const request = {
              name: mlClient.datasetPath('dumb-269602', 'us-central1', args.datasetInput.datasetId),
              inputConfig: {
                gcsSource: {
                  inputUris: args.datasetInput.path.split(','),
                },
              },
            };

            // Import dataset
            console.log(`Proccessing import`);
            const [operation] = await mlClient.importData(request);

            // Wait for operation to complete.
            const [response] = await operation.promise();
            console.log(`Dataset imported: ${response}`);
            return {
              datasetId: args.datasetInput.datasetId,
              status: 200
            }

          } catch (err) {
            return {
              datasetId: args.datasetInput.datasetId,
              status: 404
            }
          }
}
```

Link to the actual page on GCP: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/datasets

Comment: Can we get a look at your gcp-ql.js code where you're invoking the "importDataset" function? Could it be that somehow you're calling it twice?

Comment: I am invoking the function using the graphQL playground. And I'm only calling it once.

Comment: I'm not very experienced in graphQL, but which Apollo version are you using? It might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/2501#issue-425895926) that I found regarding QueryBuilder object executing queries multiple times.
A workaround seems to be [this](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/1143#issuecomment-509561227)

Comment: "apollo-server": "^2.10.1", (from package.json).

Comment: Do you require any specific features from version 2.10.1? Could you try to downgrade to 1.4 and try again to see if this is related to the above mentioned [issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/2501#issue-425895926)? Also, have you tried [this workaround](https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/1143#issuecomment-509561227)?